# spritekit scene transition works incorrect

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

im having a trouble in scene transition at spritekit application written on swift 4

I have a gameover.swift file declaring EndScene class:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class EndScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var RestartButton : UIButton!
var HighScore : Int!
var HighScoreLabel : UILabel!
var GameOverLabel : UILabel!
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.scene?.backgroundColor = SKColor.white

    RestartButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: view.frame.size.width/3
        , height: 30))
    RestartButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    RestartButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2 , y: view.frame.size.height/1.5)
    RestartButton.setTitle("restart", for: UIControlState.normal)
    RestartButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
    RestartButton.setTitleColor(SKColor.black, for:  UIControlState.normal)
    RestartButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EndScene.Restart), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(RestartButton)




    GameOverLabel = UILabel (frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: view.frame.size.width/3.8, height: 30))
    GameOverLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2 , y: view.frame.size.height/10)
    GameOverLabel.textColor = SKColor.red
    GameOverLabel.text = "Game Over"
    self.view?.addSubview(GameOverLabel)

}

func Restart(){
    RestartButton.removeFromSuperview()
    GameOverLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(), transition: SKTransition.reveal(with: .up, duration: 0.3))


}

 }
```

GameScene is a class declared in GameScene.swift file. It contains declaration of class describing game process.

The problem is:

when the game starts from GameScene it works correct (all objects are drown and physics work) but when i restart game from EndScene it works incorrect (1 object is drown from time to time but every other objects aren't drown, even background color isn't drown).

What in general can be with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't just create a `GameScene` by calling its parameterless initializer. Look at how `GameScene` is presented in the generated `GameViewController.swift` file. You will see that it calls `(fileNamed:)` initializer.

So change this line:

```
self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(), transition: SKTransition.reveal(with: .up, duration: 0.3))
```

To

```
self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene"), transition: SKTransition.reveal(with: .up, duration: 0.3))
```